# Highcharts - Drilldown drill up button theme styles not working

Tags: highcharts

I am on highcharts version 9.3.3 and for some reason cannot upgrade the version.
I have tried styling up the drill-up button in drilldown but drillup.theme styling doesn't seem to work.
Interestingly it worked nicely in latest version.

```
drilldown: {
        drillUpButton: {
            relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
            position: {
                y: 0,
                x: 0
            },
            theme: {
                fill: 'white',
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: 'silver',
                r: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#a4edba'
                    },
                    select: {
                        stroke: '#039',
                        fill: '#a4edba'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [...]
    }
```

JSFiddle where its not working: https://jsfiddle.net/1gcprumk/

JSFiddle where it is working on latest highcharts version: https://jsfiddle.net/e0o7hxw9/

Can anyone please help what am I doing wrong. Or it is a bug in highcharts version 9.3.3?

Answer (score 0):

In version 10.0.0, `breadcrumbs` appeared and replaced the `drillUpButton` functionality, and with this change, the view and styling of the button changed. With this change, the `drillUpButton` property was deprecated.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, because in the 2nd demo you sent, `drillUpButton` does not affect the button, so it has a default appearance and location. For example, if you want to move the button to the left in the older version, you can do it like this:

```js
drilldown: {
  drillUpButton: {
    position: {
      align: 'left'
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ldetoh4n/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.drillUpButton.position